# How to remove the 1985-04-12`T`23:20:50 in `datetime-local`

Tags: html

**Question:** how do i remove the `T` in:

**Question 2 :** How do i add seconds

```
<input type="datetime-local"/>
```

**Output:** `1985-04-12T23:20:50`

I want to remove the `T` and add seconds to the end `00:00:00`

Comment: That's the only allowed [local date and time string](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/common-microsyntaxes.html#concept-datetime-local), though.

Comment: Is there a way to remove it when i send it to string?

Comment: Where do you send it to? Isn't it easier to just remove it afterward?

Comment: I think that when you say "add seconds" you mean "remove time information" (and leave just date). Is that correct?

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález Like `ymdHms` and no `T`

Comment: Alright, I misunderstood your specs then. Could you please edit the question and provide the desired output for the sample input you've already shown? Also, does it need to be accomplished with static HTML?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot, as long as the content should stay legal for a `<input type="datetime-local">`. As per 4.10.5.1.12, the contents of a local date and time input element must be parseable:

> #### [4.10.5.1.12. Local Date and Time state (`type=datetime-local`)](http://%20https://www.w3.org/TR/2017/CR-html52-20170808/sec-forms.html#local-date-and-time-state-typedatetimelocal)
>
> When an input element’s type attribute is in the Local Date and Time state, the rules in this section apply.
>
> The input element represents a control for setting the element’s value to a string representing a Local Date and Time, with no time-zone offset information.
>
> If the element is mutable, the user agent should allow the user to change the Date and Time represented by its value, as obtained by parsing a date and time from it. ***User agents must not allow the user to set the value to a non-empty string that is not a [valid normalized global date and time string](https://www.w3.org/TR/2017/CR-html52-20170808/infrastructure.html#valid-normalized-global-date-and-time-string).***

A normalized local date and time *always* includes a `T`:

> ### [2.4.5.7. Global dates and times](https://www.w3.org/TR/2017/CR-html52-20170808/infrastructure.html#valid-normalized-global-date-and-time-string)
>
> …
> A string is a valid normalized global date and time string representing a date, time, and a time-zone offset if it consists of the following components in the given order:
>
> 1. A valid date string representing the date converted to the UTC time zone
> 2. A U+0054 LATIN CAPITAL LETTER T character (T)
> 3. A valid time string representing the time converted to the UTC time zone and expressed as the shortest possible string for the given time (e.g., omitting the seconds component entirely if the given time is zero seconds past the minute)
> 4. A U+005A LATIN CAPITAL LETTER Z character (Z)

Therefore, you cannot expect your browser to remove the additional information. You can, however, copy the information to a hidden `<input>` tag with JavaScript and send that instead. Alternatively, have the server remove the superfluous information.

Keep in mind that a normalized time is really helpful, though, as local times without timezone information are ambigous.

Answer (score 0):

Although you should save the reference to the value provided, because it is a *standardize method of saving dates and times*, if you need to modify it for displaying purposes, you can do this...

`var modified_value = dateString.replace('T', ' ') + ' seconds';`

Where `dateString` is a variable with the output of your input field.

Comment: its for display purposes. will try that